proof of differential is the scalar product with gradient: $D_g(x)(v) = \nabla(g)(x)\cdot v$
I'm looking for a proof of this classical result for a differentiable multivariate function $g$:
let $D_g(x)$ be the differentiate (I also find total derivative) of $g$ at point $x$: $D_g(x)(v) = \nabla(g)(x)\cdot v$
My starting points are the following:
A function $g$ is differentiable in $x$ means that there is a linear function (often called also a linear map) $D_g(x)(v)$ such that $g(x+v) = g(x)+D_g(x)(v)+o(\lVert v\rVert)$
Gradient is defined as the vector of partial derivatives defined as below:
$\frac{dg}{dx_i}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+he_i)-g(x)}{h}$ where $e_i$ is the $i^{th}$ vector of the canonical base.
The actual property can be splitted in two:

if the $g$ is differentiable, then it admits a gradient
$D_g(x)(v) = \nabla(g)(x)\cdot v$

I found many ressources for definitions and list of properties, such as this one or this other one but I'm missing a proof.
This video seems to takes the property as the definition of differentiability, and then proves the formula for directional derivative. Yet the definition of $D_g(x)$ seems more general (this is, for instance, the one that is used in Rademacher's theorem), and its expression as a scalar product, a consequence.
I know it's a very fundamental result of multivariate calculus and even a mere link to a more complete lecture would be appreciated.

Can you provide a bit more detail on what you are allowed to assume? The statement you are proving is often taken to be the definition of the gradient. To go the other way requires, at a minimum, knowing that the total derivative is a linear functional and that all such linear functionals can be expressed as an inner product with some vector.

As @whpowell96 said the gradient can be uniquely defined through the requirement that $$\forall v:Dg(x)(v)=\langle \nabla g(x),v\rangle$$and in this case there is nothing to prove.

In my original question I forgot the linearity in the definition of differentiable.
With linearity the proof is actually straightforward.

use $v=e_i$ and differentiability definition shows that the limit defining partial derivative exists. Thus we have $\frac{dg}{dx_i}(x) = D_g(x)(e_i)$
$v = \sum_i\lambda_i e_i$ and $D_g(x)$ linear wrt $v$ thus $D_g(x)(v) = \sum_i \lambda_i D_g(x)(e_i)=\sum_i \lambda_i\frac{dg}{dx_i}(x)=\nabla(g)(x)\cdot v$

